# overflow:hidden at a certain height > on hover displays all?

Tags: css

I have an:

```
.itembox {
```

class, where many items in a directory type website are displayed. I think it would be cool to `overflow:hidden`  at a certain height, and have a small `1px solid #AAA` under, **then when hover over > It displays full.** Is this fairly simple using my global class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty much trivial. Add a `max-height` as well as your `overflow:hidden`, then on the `:hover` version of the class remove the `max-height` (by setting it to a very high number).

```
.itembox {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.itembox:hover {
    max-height: 9999px;
}
```

Comment: expanding on Kolink's solution, you can add the max-height to your class, then attach a jQuery (you tagged it) hover event that removes the max height and slides the content down to its content height.

Comment: very true.  CSS3 animations would be cool, but [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qs3E8/1/) should be cross-browser compatible

Comment: [here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qs3E8/2/) that does the CSS3 transition mentioned.  While it doesnt work in all browsers, it does have the benefit of being javascript free and degrading nicely.